# Resize photo that is extracted from a link

Tags: php, image-processing

I am pulling tweets from a database that include URLs that link to a photo.

I've been able to display the photos on my site but they are just too big.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ( $entities->media as $media ) {

$tweet_text =str_ireplace($media->url,  '<a href="'.$media->expanded_url.'">'
.$media->display_url.'</a>', $tweet_text);

{
$media_html = '';
$url = $media->media_url_https;
$link = $media->url;
$width = $media->sizes->w;
$height = $media->sizes->h;

  $media_html = "<a href=\"" . $url . "\" target='_blank'>";
  $media_html .=  "<img src=\"" . $url . "\" width=\"" .$width.
     "\" height=\"" .$height. "\" />";
  $media_html .= "</a><br />";          
 $media_html .= $tweet_text;    

    }
return $media_html;
```

I've tried doing:

```
$width = $media->sizes->w;
$height = $media->sizes->h;
$width = ($width)/2;
$height = ($height)/2;
```

but it just isn't displaying after that.
I've tried many variations and the only thing I can get to work is if I add

```
$width = $media->sizes->w+100;
$height = $media->sizes->h+100;
```

But this just changes the w and h to 100, and as you know, most pictures aren't perfect squares!

What do you all think?

Comment: what library are you loading the image into? you reference `$media` as an object, but what type of object is `$media`?

Comment: I added more of the code to help you understand. I really just want to cut the width and height in half to help with load time. I tried using thumbnails, and they were just terrible quality.

Comment: Not sure if resizing an image using that method will help with load time, I think the full size image is downloaded regardless. Does printing the sizes from $media show the values you'd expect before any changes?

Comment: Well, I'm calling a php script to load tweets that contain the URL, which contains the picture. If I don't use this script, the photo never loads anyways, so with that logic, why wouldn't re-sizing the photo before loading help? I'm really not sure if it would or wouldn't, just asking for clarification. ------- and also I tried printing the sizes but it wouldn't show because of the way the site is setup, I might be able to test it on a different page if that is something you need me to do for you to understand better. I'm new at all this, and I've tried my best to learn before bothering anyone

Comment: I'm a bit of a novice in this area, but from my understanding, in the code you've posted the PHP is setting the size and url of the image and returning it as a string of html, it is still left up to the users browser to display the html. With that in mind the users browser downloads whatever image is at the url then renders it using the dimensions given. The printing was to see if the values are set, for it to end up at 100 it would have to be 0 or empty. You could try using PHPs getimagesize() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to test the w/h  direct from the url

Answer (score 0):

By adding

```
$RESULT = list($width, $height) = getimagesize($url);
```

I was able to return the value. It was an array so I couldn't divide the `$width` or `$height` without adding that first.

```
   {
$media_html = '';
$url = $media->media_url_https;
$link = $media->url;
$width = $media->sizes->w;
$height = $media->sizes->h;

$RESULT = list($width, $height) = getimagesize($url);

$width = ($width)/2;
$height = ($height)/2;

  $media_html = "<a href=\"" . $url . "\" target='_blank'>";
  $media_html .=  "<img src=\"" . $url . "\" width=\"" .$width.
  "\" height=\"" .$height. "\" />";
  $media_html .= "</a><br />";          
  $media_html .= $tweet_text;

    }

return $media_html;
```

Comment: It's actually gotten worse on loading times though! I read on other posts that I should save the $width and $height values in another temp file but where this is always changing, I'm not sure how to go about doing this